# jQuery countUp.js with abbreviated numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to utilize countUp.js (https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/) to run a number counter animation. However, I'd like to format the numbers as they count to include abbreviations, e.g. starting from "100k" and counting up to "1m"

I've been able to abbreviate numbers before using JS, but I'm unsure how I would go about altering or utilizing countUp.js to include the re-formatting at the same time. Also open to using a different number counting JS plugin. Any examples or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can provide a formatting function called formattingFn as one of the options when using the library. From the source: `formattingFn: formatNumber, // optional custom formatting function, default is formatNumber above`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Daniel you can use the `formattingFn` function for this.

You start off by defining a range of numbers you want to include in the format:

```
var ranges = [
  { divider: 1000000 , suffix: 'M' },
  { divider: 1000 , suffix: 'k' }
];
```

Then, you pass along a custom function as the `formattingFn` option to abbreviate your numbers:

```
formattingFn: (n) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
        if (n >= ranges[i].divider) {
            return (n / ranges[i].divider).toString() + ranges[i].suffix;
        }
    }
    return n.toString();
}
```

To demonstrate how you would apply that together with the demo on the link you provided I have created this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0cg1caka/4/